# Xamarin IOS. Reference between xib control and UICollectionViewCell.cs was lost

Tags: ios, xamarin, reference, uicollectionviewcell

I'm novice in **xamarin**, sorry if this is a stupid question. Some time before, I had added `UICollectionViewCell` via **mac vs studio**. The studio generated two files : `xib` and `UICollectionViewCell`.cs. The reference between both these files worked correctly in the beginning (when I was adding/changing any control in xib file by designer, then the autogenerated code had been changed as well).

But after undeterminated changes from my side(actually, I think, I had not done anything to be reason of this problem), this reference was lost. Now, when I'm changing anything in UI designer, nothing is changing in `UICollectionViewCell`.cs file.

These files are placed in the same directory.

Also, I don't remember what the `File's Owner` class field setting contained before. Currently, this field is empty, but filling of this file by `UICollectionViewCell`.cs class doesn't help.

I think. it is well known issue, could anyone help with it?

Comment: Just to make my question easier, what place do I need to check to see the reference between xib and .cs code in?
As I may see, File's owner property in xib designer is not right place for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was happened but when I made checkout to previous branch and then came back to current, the problem was disappeared. Currently the reference is working. Hope it was something temporaly :(